# TideSDK keep window set on top (transparent overlay)

Tags: tidesdk

I'm looking to make a small app using TideSDK, but would like to have the window sit in the bottom right and always on top of other windows

e.g. like a transparent overlay showing a graph or some information that is always visible regardless of switching focus to other windows

Is this doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on the tiapp.xml define:

```
<transparent-background>true</transparent-background>
```

on css define:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        background : transparent;
    }
</style>
```

on your javascript call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ti.UI.currentWindow.setTopMost ( true );
    Ti.UI.currentWindow.moveTo ( display.width-your.app.width, display.height-your.app.height );
</script>
```